How to create legend with two columns for one label
I want to create a pie chart in matplotlib with the same legend as on the photo below, meaning that I want to divide each label into two columns, so the percentage will be equally separated from the name.

I tried calculating total width for each name and adding missing number of spaces, however due to the different width of each letter (I’m using custom font), this solution doesn’t work:

Could you please help me if there is another way to do that?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import pandas as pd

data = {'names': ['North America', 'Europe', 'Japan', 'Emerging Asia', 'Latin America', 'Cash'],
        'values': [76, 14, 4, 4, 0, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie(
    df['values'], 
    startangle=90, 
    wedgeprops={'width': 0.3},
)

def get_text_width(text, font_properties):
    text_obj = plt.text(0, 0, text, fontproperties=font_properties)
    bbox = text_obj.get_window_extent()
    return bbox.width

font_properties = fm.FontProperties()
names_width = [get_text_width(name, font_properties) for name in df['names']]
max_name_width = max(names_width)
space_width = get_text_width(' ', font_properties)
num_of_spaces = [int((max_name_width-names_width[i])/space_width) for i in range(len(names_width))]
legend_labels = [f'{n}{' '*spaces}   {v}%' for n, spaces, v in zip(df['names'], num_of_spaces, df['values'])]

ax.legend(
    legend_labels,
    bbox_to_anchor=(0.7,0.1),
)

plt.show()


See Matplotlib Legend string formatting / Align for an approach with a mono-spaced font, so spaces can be used to align the legend.

Thank you for your help. I added my code. Unfortunately, I have to use custom font which isn't mono-spaced (for the purpose of showing what is my problem, I generated the legend using the default font). Do you know any other solution? What do you mean by adding legend "manually"?

As suggested before, instead of using ax.legend(...), you could call ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle(...)) and ax.text() several times to draw rectangles and text to resemble a legend.
